# .stop() breaks the fadein and the yellow box doesn't appear proper

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I most over the red box quickly and leave the cursor over the red box, it simply stops fading in and breaks the operation in half. If I don't use the .stop() function at all, jquery tries to finish the remaining operations (that I hovered and quit the box quickly before) Does anyone know what I should do here? Thanks.

**http://jsfiddle.net/dkLhC/1**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box1").mouseenter(function(){

    $(".box2").stop().fadeIn();
  });
  $(".box1").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".box2").stop().fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that the correct answer is

`true, false` (for the parameters `clearQueue, jumpToEnd`)

**http://jsfiddle.net/q6d57/11/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box1").mouseenter(function(){
    $('.box2').stop(true, false).fadeIn(3000);
  });
  $(".box1").mouseleave(function(){
    $('.box2').stop(true, false).fadeOut(3000);
  });
});
```

Comment: The second parameter is false by default, so you can just omit it.

Answer (score 3):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkLhC/8/)

JQuery function [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) also seems to work like css transitions, but transitions are undoubtedly better choice.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box1").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".box2").stop().fadeTo(1000, 1);
  });
  $(".box1").mouseleave(function(){
      $(".box2").stop().fadeTo(1000, 0);
  });
});
```

Comment: Does the code in my update works wrong?

Comment: Could you explan what is wrong with it?

Comment: For me these two versions: http://jsfiddle.net/q6d57/5/ and http://jsfiddle.net/dkLhC/8/ work exatly the same. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I see this difference, but I asked you about version from my update. There was update with using fadeTo function. Don't you see it?

Comment: If you open dev tools in any browser you will see that when you use fadeIn or fadeOut - opacity is changing. Maybe you can't change your vote because you changed it a lot yesterday. After the day passed you will be able to change it again.

Comment: it should be true, false ,and not true, true. so your answer is not correct.

Comment: Is my answer correct now?

Comment: it's not correct ,but I give you +1 for your efforts. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your problem, but an alternative solution. Instead of jQuery, you can use [`CSS transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to do the fade in and out

```css
.box2
{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}

.box1:hover + .box2 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cRU/)

Comment: CSS is still first choice when possible

Answer (score 0):

Use [.finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dkLhC/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box1").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".box2").finish().fadeIn();
  });
  $(".box1").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".box2").finish().fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice , this is an almost same as `stop(true, true)`

Comment: @PSL "It differs, however, in that .finish() also causes the CSS property of all queued animations to jump to their end values, as well." ;)